# Get client_credentials token with base64 encoded client/secret in header with League/Oauth2 client

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, clientcredential, thephpleague

I'm implementing a service integration with an oauth2 authentication with `client credentials` grant type.

In postman I can get the token in the final request itself, by using the Authorization tab. I must set "*Client Authentication*" as "**Send as Basic Auth header**" otherwise I get an "unauthorized_client" error.

When I try to get the token in my code, using https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client It simply doesn't work throwing each time the "unauthorized_client" error.

This is because it's behaving as postman with the "**Send client credentials in body**" option set.

Is there an option I'm missing to do the same thing with the oauth2 client?
If I take a look at the Postman console, it's clear that it sets an "Authorization" header, with "Basic xxxxxx" where xxxxxx is the Base64 encoding of `clientID:clientSecret` for the request that asks for the token.

While if it sends the `cliend_id` / `client_secret` as body params it throws that error.